# A way to determine whether or not a website validates

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I am developing a service, and it needs to be able to determine whether or not a specific website on the internet validates (with 0 errors).

Does the W3C have an API?

---

Also, I would like to be able to do a browser-by-browser test. I mean, I would also like to be able to tell if [the first criteria cannot be met] any 1 (or more) particular website(s) fail(s) to validate (with 0 errors). Is this currently possible?

I am still searching, but have yet to find this out.

Comment: Could you please clarify the second paragraph?

Comment: @ZetaTwo - is it possible to "ask" a validation api if a particular website works properly (i.e has no compatibility issues) with a specified web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C has APIs for both their HTML and CSS validators.

The HTML validator docs are found at: http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html

The CSS validator docs are found at: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html

Comment: Thank you Zeta Two, I couldn't find those ones.